# How to Remove Existing Weight From A Geometric Network

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, geometric-network

I have seen the solution to "[Remove Connectivity Rule From Geometric Network](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/remove-connectivity-rule-from-geometric-network.htm)" using ArcGIS ArcPy, but in my case I need to remove an existing **Weight** from the Geometric Network.

Can you please let me know if there is a way to do this through ArcPy or ArcMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Managing a geometric network](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geometric-networks/managing-a-geometric-network.htm) (emphasis mine)

> Any of the following will **require you to delete and re-create your**
>   **geometric network**:
>
> - You need to add a new populated feature class to the network.
> - **You need to remove a weight from the network.**
> - The snapping tolerance was too small on the previous build.
> - You need to change a feature class from a simple edge to a complex edge or vice versa.
> - You need to add a specific junction feature class as a source or sink, or remove its ancillary role.
> - You want to rename the geometric network.